# Next Js serialized as JSON ServerSideProps issue

Tags: json, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I can't seem to figure out the problem with this ServerSide code in NextJS.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const genre = context.query.genre;

  const request = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      requests[genre]?.url || requests.fetchTrending.url
    }`
  ).then((res)=> res.json());
 
  return {
    props: {
      results: request.results,
    },
  };
}
```

Error: Error serializing `.results` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

Comment: Is the request returning the expected output? From the error `request.results` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const gener = context.query.gener;
  const request = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3${requests[gener]?.url || requests.fetchTrending.url}`).then((res) => res.json())
  return {
    props: {
      results: request.results
    }
  }
}
```

and then
export default function Home({ results }){ your jsx}